# foreach binding for only one <td> element in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockout binding in my one of MVC project.

I want to apply foreach binding on single

```
 <table>
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>MarginType</th>
                 @foreach (var discountGroup in Model.CustomerDiscountGroups)
                        {
                            <th>
                                @discountGroup.Code
                            </th>
                        }
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: MarginTypes">
          <tr>
             <td data-bind="foreach:CustomerDiscountGroups">
                  <span data-bind="text:Code"> </span>
           </td>
        </tr>    
</tbody>
```

I want to repeat the 2nd td with the no of customerdiscountgroups.

Comment: can you also share dummy response what you want?

Comment: Repeat the `<td>` or output each `CustomerDiscountGroups` within the same cell? Either way [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/c59vL/) has both.

Comment: Thanks.. From your example, solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need for each for that, nor that inner `<TH>`

```
<tr>     
      <th>MarginType</th>
           <th>
                 @Model.CustomerDiscountGroups.First().Code
           </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if you want to repeat the `<td>` for each item in your `CustomerDiscountGroups`, then you could put the `foreach` on the `<tr>`.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: MarginTypes">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: CustomerDiscountGroups">
    <td>
      <span data-bind="text:Code"> </span>
    </td>
  </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Comment: But I don't want to repeat all <td>. Just only for each customerDiscountGroups I want to reapeat that <td>. I have other single <td> in my table. Here I have shown only one which is MarginTypeName

Comment: If you don't want to repeat all of the `CustomerDiscountGroups`, then don't use a `foreach`. I just don't understand. An example of the output you are trying to achieve would help a lot.